# convert JSON object to JSON tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
var obj = [{
    id: 1,
    child:[2,4],
    data : "hello"
},{
    id: 2,
    child:[3],
    data : "I m second"
},
{   
    id: 3,
    child:[],
    data : "I m third"
},
{
    id: 4,
    child:[6],
    data : "I m fourth"
},{
    id: 5,
    child:[],
    data : "I m fifth"
},{
    id: 6,
    child:[],
    data : "I m sixth"
}];
```

I have convert this object to

```
var newObj = [{
  id: 1,
  child: [{
    id: 2,
    child: [{
      id: 3,
      child: [],
      data: "I m third"
    }],
    data: "I m second"
  }, {
    id: 4,
    child: [{
      id: 6,
      child: [],
      data: "I m sixth"
    }],
    data: "I m fourth"
  }],
  data: "hello"
}, {
  id: 5,
  child: [],
  data: "I m fifth"
}];
```

which is nothing but tree format of JSON based on child array of each property. How to approach the problem ?? How to code in javascript ??

Any help would appreciable. Thanks in advance.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rajan_Singh/wydfaq22/)

Comment: Sorry, it's really hard to understand what you're trying to do. What did you tried so far? The only thing I can see are 2 arrays of objects.

Comment: Actually this is a good question. I don't see the point of the downvotes.

Comment: @Brduca I have to convert obj to newObj.

Answer (score 1):

A proposal with a temporary object for keeping the reference to the items.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, child: [2, 4], data: "hello" }, { id: 2, child: [3], data: "I m second" }, { id: 3, child: [], data: "I m third" }, { id: 4, child: [6], data: "I m fourth" }, { id: 5, child: [], data: "I m fifth" }, { id: 6, child: [], data: "I m sixth" }],
    tree = [];

array.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.id]) {
        this[a.id] = { id: a.id };
        tree.push(this[a.id]);
    }
    this[a.id].data = a.data;
    this[a.id].child = a.child.map(function (b) {
        this[b] = this[b] || { id: b };
        return this[b];
    }, this);
}, Object.create(null));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Hi Nina , what `Object.create(null)` doing ? Please explain ?

Comment: it creates a really empty object -- an object without any prototypes.

Comment: I want to know why we are doing it here ??

Comment: oh, i see, its the thisArgs of the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop. inside its addressed with `this`, a temp variable.

Answer (score 1):

Well ok.. as i have commented this one was a good question and it was a pleasure to give some thinking over it. Obviously this turns out to be harder than flattening an array of nested objects.

By the way the algorithm doesn't rely on any correlation between the object's ids and the objects keys in the array. An object with any id can be anywhere in the array.

```js
var obj = [{ id: 1, child: [2, 4], data: "hello" }, { id: 2, child: [3], data: "I m second" }, { id: 3, child: [], data: "I m third" }, { id: 4, child: [6], data: "I m fourth" }, { id: 5, child: [], data: "I m fifth" }, { id: 6, child: [], data: "I m sixth" }];

function construct(flat){
  function nest(o) {
    o.forEach( c => { if (!!c.child.length) { // coolness starts here
                         c.child = c.child.map( e => flat.splice(flat.findIndex( f => f.id == e),1)[0]);
                         nest(c.child);
                         }
                 });
  }
  nest(flat);
  return flat;
}

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(construct(obj), null, 2) + "</pre>");
```

Comment: thanks  this is what I wanted !! Can you tell me what is actually happening inside for each loop.

Comment: Hi... It works like this; We are passing a flat array to the inner `nest()` function. The `nest` function walks on each element of the passed array one by one (`forEach` loop) If the current element (`c` parameter) has child (`!!child.length` - !! is boolean convertion 0 becomes false and any other number becomes true) replaces the c.child array elements with the objects from the flat array with the corresponding id (c.child.map) however the objects moved from flat array to child array must be deleted from the flat array. This is done by `flat.splice`

Comment: @Rajan Singh : Splice is very handy because it both deletes the element and returns the deleted element. So what happens is, a search for element with correct id (findIndex) delete and return that indexed element from flat array and map it to the position in the child array in the place of it's id. So we construct the child array with the objects. Child array is now like another flat array because the elements in child array can contain their children. So we make a recursive call to nest(child) and the same story applies this time for the child array. This is the reason for inner nest function