# how to transform a hierarchical csv (semicolon separated) into a multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, d3.js, multidimensional-array

I have hierarchical data in a csv: the different levels are separated by a semicolon, the value is separated by a comma (at the end of the "line"):

```
Parent1;Child1;Grandchild1;3;3,5
Parent1;Child1;Grandchild2;3;3,5
Parent2;Child2;Grandchild2;4,4
Parent3;Child4;Grandchild1;5,5
```

and I want to use javascript/jQuery/d3.js to transform it into a multi-dimensional array which looks like this:

```
var tree = [
  {
    text: "Parent 1",
    nodes: [
      {
        text: "Child 1",
        nodes: [
          {
            text: "Grandchild 1"
          },
          {
            text: "Grandchild 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: "Child 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 2"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 3"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 4"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 5"
  }
];
```

The difficulty seems to be that I need to loop recursively and be careful about the depth of the array (i don't want the value to be part of my multidimensional array).

At the moment my code looks like this, but it's not working correctly:

```
function createNavi(jsonRoot){

function printParentAddChildren(parent){

    var parentObj = {};
    parentObj.text = parent.name; 
    parentObj.backColor = colors[parent.depth];

    var children = parent.children;//array of objects(children)
    if(children==null)return parentObj;

    parentObj.node = [];

    for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
        parentObj.node.push(printParentAddChildren(children[i]));    
    }
    return parentObj; 
}

    var tree = [];
    var children = jsonRoot.children; //array of objects(children)
    for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
        tree.push(printParentAddChildren(children[i]));    
    }
    $('#tree').treeview({
          data: tree
    });
    console.log(tree);   
};
```

I guess that's easy for some of you guys out there! **Thank you in advance for your efforts!**

Comment: In `Parent1;Child1;Grandchild1;3;3,5` what does 3;3,5 mean

Comment: @Redu 3;3; are part of the hierarchical structure (for example "3" means route number three. The hierarchical structure could look like this: `2014;November;Monday;3;2,5` and mean this: In **November 2014 route** (number) **three** was built by person number **2** in _**5**_hours). 5, which is separated by a comma and at the end of the line, is the value of that branch --> 5 hours. The data is used for comparison purposes.

Comment: Yes i got it but where do you want to save them in your tree? In your example they are not indicated? In any case i will implement this tomorrow since it's already 3 AM here and i have to take some rest. By the way i did something similar very recently. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/36942348/4543207

Comment: @Redu No, i don't want them to save in my tree. No, they're not indicated? I checked your given example, but i wasn't able to use it for my case. The user down below found a solution, but it's not 100% what i need (i need the attribute "Parent1", "Child1" or whatever to be a **text**, not a _key_.

Comment: I guess my answer below serves your purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the sort of thing `d3.nest` is meant to do.

Given a file *test.csv* like:

```
p;c;g;r1;r2
Parent1;Child1;Grandchild1;3;3,5
Parent1;Child1;Grandchild2;3;3,5
Parent2;Child2;Grandchild2;4,4
Parent3;Child4;Grandchild1;5,5
```

This:

```
var dsv = d3.dsv(";", "text/plain");
  dsv("test.csv", function(data){
    var n = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d){ return d.p })
      .key(function(d){ return d.c })
      .key(function(d){ return d.g })
      .entries(data);
  });
```

Produces n as:

```
[{
  "key": "Parent1",
  "values": [{
    "key": "Child1",
    "values": [{
      "key": "Grandchild1",
      "values": [{
        "p": "Parent1",
        "c": "Child1",
        "g": "Grandchild1",
        "r1": "3",
        "r2": "3,5"
      }]
    }, {
      "key": "Grandchild2",
      "values": [{
        "p": "Parent1",
        "c": "Child1",
        "g": "Grandchild2",
        "r1": "3",
        "r2": "3,5"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "key": "Parent2",
  "values": [{
    "key": "Child2",
    "values": [{
      "key": "Grandchild2",
      "values": [{
        "p": "Parent2",
        "c": "Child2",
        "g": "Grandchild2",
        "r1": "4,4"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "key": "Parent3",
  "values": [{
    "key": "Child4",
    "values": [{
      "key": "Grandchild1",
      "values": [{
        "p": "Parent3",
        "c": "Child4",
        "g": "Grandchild1",
        "r1": "5,5"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}]
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mCgl1c4dllopqkEDzzZk?p=preview).

---

**EDITS FOR COMMENTS**

```
  var dsv = d3.dsv(";", "text/plain");
  dsv("test.csv", function(data){
    var n = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d){ return d.p })
      .key(function(d){ return d.c })
      .rollup(function(d){
        return d.map(function(d1){
          return {key: d1.g};
        })
      })
      .entries(data);

    function renameKeys(obj){
      obj.forEach(function(d){
        d.text = d.key;
        delete d.key;
        if (d.values){
          d.nodes = d.values;
          delete d.values;
          renameKeys(d.nodes);
        }
      });
    }

    renameKeys(n);

  });
```

Produces:

```
[{
  "text": "Parent1",
  "nodes": [{
    "text": "Child1",
    "nodes": [{
      "text": "Grandchild1"
    }, {
      "text": "Grandchild2"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "text": "Parent2",
  "nodes": [{
    "text": "Child2",
    "nodes": [{
      "text": "Grandchild2"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "text": "Parent3",
  "nodes": [{
    "text": "Child4",
    "nodes": [{
      "text": "Grandchild1"
    }]
  }]
}]
```

Updated [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/xzWgDl8QFuLdGFBJBF9Z?p=preview).

Comment: Is there another way? Because the d3.nest() function defines a key. As my example shows, the parent node should be text: var tree = [ { text: "Parent 1", nodes: [ { text: "Child 1", nodes: [ { text: "Grandchild 1" }, { text: "Grandchild 2" } ] }, { text: "Child 2" } ] }, { text: "Parent 2" }, { text: "Parent 3" }, { text: "Parent 4" }, { text: "Parent 5" } ];

Comment: @J.B., unless you are adhering to some strict specification the the object property names usually aren't that important.  Regardless see edits above for strict adherence to you standard.

Comment: ., **this nice! Thank you very much! I appreciate your help!**

Answer (score 0):

Well i guess this is as far as it gets on pure JS. As you see it's not tons of code but slightly a complicated one. Let me first show the code and then i will go through it.

```js
var csv = "Parent1;Child1;Grandchild1;3;3,5\nParent1;Child1;Grandchild2;3;3,5\nParent2;Child2;Grandchild2;4,4\nParent3;Child4;Grandchild1;5,5";

function construct(csv){
  var arr = csv.split("\n").map(e => e.match(/[A-Za-z]+\d*/g));
  function nest(a,p){
    var fi = p.findIndex(e => e.text == a[0]);
    ~fi ? "nodes" in p[fi] ? nest(a.slice(1),p[fi].nodes)
                           : a.length > 1 && (p[fi].nodes = nest(a.slice(1),[]))
        : (p.push({"text": a[0]}),
           nest(a,p));
    return p;
  }
  return arr.reduce((p,c) => {p = nest(c,p); return p},[]);
}

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(construct(csv), null, 2) + "</pre>")
```

OK `construct` function takes the csv text and first things first converts into an array of arrays holding each words in each line as items such as

```
[ [ 'Parent1', 'Child1', 'Grandchild1' ],
  [ 'Parent1', 'Child1', 'Grandchild2' ],
  [ 'Parent2', 'Child2', 'Grandchild2' ],
  [ 'Parent3', 'Child4', 'Grandchild1' ] ]
```

The `construct` function is in charge of constructing the outermost array which has the parent objects as items. It does this job by utilizing an `Array.prototype.reduce()` implementation with an initial value of an empty array. The `nest` function handles inner array elements recursively and it is where all the blackmagic happens.

Comment: ., **Thank you so much for your effort!** It's all going now!